# Linking error when casting IDXGIAdapter1 to IDXGIAdapter4 [DirectX and WinRT/C++]

Tags: c++, directx, c++-winrt

I'm trying to cast IDXGIAdapter1 instance to IDXGIAdapter4 like so:

```
winrt::com_ptr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;

winrt::com_ptr<IDXGIAdapter4> adapter{adapters.front().as<IDXGIAdapter4>()};
```

But there is linking error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WINRT_GetRestrictedErrorInfo referenced in function "public: __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::hresult_error(struct winrt::hresult,struct winrt::hresult_error::from_abi_t)" (??0hresult_error@winrt@@QEAA@Uhresult@1@Ufrom_abi_t@01@@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WINRT_RoOriginateLanguageException referenced in function "private: void __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::originate(struct winrt::hresult,void *)" (?originate@hresult_error@winrt@@AEAAXUhresult@2@PEAX@Z)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I know what is your adapters? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem cause is 78th line https://codeshare.io/G6bVom And my adapter is nVidia 2060 RTX Super

Comment: If you tried to use QueryInterface(e.g. `HRESULT hr = (adapters.front())->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter4), (void**)&adapter);`), can it work for you?

Comment: Yes, that works. Also works like that ```auto hr = adapters.front()->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter4), winrt::put_abi(adapter));```. But if I try to check result ```winrt::check_hresult(hr)``` it fails as previous time. Why linker do fail to resolve external symbols? Do I need to provide a library or something?

Comment: Do you mean when you put `winrt::check_hresult(hr)` after `HRESULT hr = (adapters.front())->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter4), (void**)&adapter);`, it will fail? When I tested it, it worked well, didn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: I mean, if I have ```auto hr = (adapters.front()->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter4), (void**)&adapter));
    winrt::check_hresult(hr);``` lines then the linker signals the same error as before - `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WINRT_GetRestrictedErrorInfo referenced in function "public: __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::hresult_error(struct winrt::hresult,struct winrt::hresult_error::from_abi_t)" (??0hresult_error@winrt@@QEAA@Uhresult@1@Ufrom_abi_t@01@@Z) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by linking "RuntimeObject.lib" library. Thank you for your help, Faywang - MSFT.